# Only show if not included?

Tags: php, include

I have a php script, and i'd like it so that it will only show this certain text if you're viewing the page in your browser, and it's not included by another script..

For example

```
//foo.php
<?php
   if(!included){
      echo "You can only see this if this is the page you're viewing";
   }
?>

//bar.php
<?php
  include 'foo.php';
?>
```

Now, When you view "bar.php", you should not see the text.. But if you open foo.php instead, you will.. How would i do this..? If at all possible..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not possible per se, but if you are exposing the php page on a website, e.g. `example.com/bar.php`, you can check `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` if you are using apache.

```
if (basename(__FILE__) != basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
   //this is included
}
```

Comment: Why basename? I have `a/b/c/index.php` and `a/b/index.php`. When one includes the other, it fails. Without basename, it compares the full length of both, seems way  better. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

In bar.php:

```
<?php
    $included = true;
    include 'foo.php';
?>
```

In foo.php:

```
if(!isset($included)){
      echo "You can only see this if this is the page you're viewing";
}
```

Comment: I want it so that people can just use include 'foo.php'.. This is a class and I don't want them to have to use more code than they have too.. I'd like the majority of the code to be in the class.

Answer (score 1):

You should see about `array get_included_files(void)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php

It gives you a list of the included files.

Answer (score 1):

"I want it so that people can just use include 'foo.php'.. This is a class and I don't want them to have to use more code than they have too.. I'd like the majority of the code to be in the class."

**since you need this, i would recommend you class_exists function.** http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

That way you can check if your class is defined, no need to check if file is included. Because, if it's defined, it's file is included for sure.

Answer (score 0):

its always a good practice using include_once() or require_once() functions. This way you make sure the file is included only once.

define a constant in the page you are including:

```
 if(defined("ALREADY_LOADED")) {
     echo "this page was loaded already";
     die("ciao");
 }
  else {
     define("ALREADY_LOADED", 1);
 }
```

now, wherever you need this control, just define before the loading of the file:

```
 define("ALREADY_LOADED", 1);
```